# what mistake in prolog - medical diagnosis to diagnoses disease?

Tags: prolog, diagnostics, expert-system

i am making expert system to diagnose patient. and i have difficulty to ask all the questions of symptom , after that give the result of disease. Thank you for your help.

this is the rule .

> symptoms of  malaria = fever,shivering,sweating,headache.
>
> symptoms of typhus = fever, nausea,flatulence, abdominal_pain_intemittent,heart_burn,smelling_fart_or_stool.
>
> symptoms of appendicitis =  fever,nausea,abdominal_pain_intemittent, pain_in_lower_right_abdominal.

i have to ask all these 10 question to user about the symptoms , and read the answer . 
for example :

> fever ?  :  yes.
>
> shivering ?   : yes.
>
> sweating ? : no.
>
> headache ?  : no.
>
> nausea  ?   : yes.
>
> flatulence  ? : yes.
>
> abdominal_pain_intemittent  ?   : yes.
>
> heart_burn ?  : no.
>
> smelling_fart_or_stool ?  : no.
>
> pain_in_lower_right_abdominal ? : no.

after the program ask question , the program should give the result of disease like this

> the diagnoses : malaria, typhus , appendicitis.

the diagnoses are malaria, typhus , appendicitis => because there are 2 symptoms malaria, 4 symptoms of typhus, 3 symptoms of appendicitis.

> the problem of my code is the program give the result of diagnosis before all the questions are displayed.

this is the coding

```
       go :- diagnosis(X),
          write('diagnosis are : '),nl,
          write(X),nl,fail.

     diagnosis(_) :- retractall, fail.
    diagnosis(malaria) :- fever(yes), shivering(yes), sweating(yes), headache(yes).



diagnosis(tipes) :- fever(yes), nausea(yes), flatulence(yes), abdominal_pain_intemittent(yes), heart_burn(yes), smelling_fart_or_stool(yes).


diagnosis('usus buntu') :- fever(yes), nausea(yes),abdominal_pain_intemittent(yes), ain_in_lower_right_abdominal(yes).  
 fever(X) :- ask(fever,X).
shivering(X) :- ask(shivering,X).
sweating(X) :- ask(sweating,X).
headache(X) :- ask(headache,X).
nausea(X) :- ask(nausea,X).
flatulence(X) :- ask(flatulence,X). 
abdominal_pain_intemittent(X) :- ask('abdominal_pain_intemittent',X).
heart_burn(X) :- ask('heart_burn',X).

smelling_fart_or_stool(X) :- ask('smelling_fart_or stool',X).
pain_in_lower_right_abdominal(X) :- ask('pain_in_lower_right_abdominal',X).


known(yes, a, b).

ask(A, V):- known(yes, A, V), !.
ask(A, V):- known(_, A, V), !, fail.
ask(A, _):- known(yes, A, _), !, fail.
ask(A, V):- write(A:V), write('? : '), read(Y), asserta(known(Y, A, V)), Y == yes.  

retractall :- retract(known(_,_,_)).
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily see why you get diagnoses before all ten questions are asked by using `trace/0`. I recommend you give this a try because it is hugely helpful in debugging Prolog programs.

The key to undestanding is to think about how backward chaining works, that is, how Prolog answers a query. Prolog wants to answers "true" but to do that it must find the variable bindings that satisfy the query. When you ask it "go," the first thing you ask it is `diagnosis(X)`. So to prove "go" is true, it must find `X` that satisfies `diagnosis(X)`. To prove that, it must enter `diagnosis/1.` From there, you have a tasteless `retractall, fail` goal, which will be entered first and will (ultimately) always fail. From there you enter `diagnosis(malaria)`, which depends on the four symptoms of fever, shivering, sweating, and headache. So this is why Prolog prompts you for these four symptoms. Supposing you say "yes" to all four, `diagnosis(malaria)` succeeds! Then back in go, `X = malaria` and it will proceed with printing out the diagnosis.

To me, this program is a good example of a very old-school approach to writing Prolog. You have a lot of declarative stuff intermingled with your I/O, you are using the fact database as a read/write store, and you are using failure to drive certain side-effects in a procedural manner. I'm inclined to lay the blame at the feet of a professor or textbook, but either way, it will be very hard to either improve this program or comprehend Prolog with this style.

The simplest thing you can do to solve the problem is to have a separate process where you collect symptoms before engaging `diagnosis/1`. The changes would look like this:

```
go :-
    retractall,
    ask_everything,
    diagnosis(X),
    write('diagnosis are : '),nl,
    write(X),nl,fail.

ask_everything :-
    fever(yes), shivering(yes), sweating(yes), headache(yes),
    nausea(yes), flatulence(yes), abdominal_pain_intemittent(yes),
    heart_burn(yes), smelling_fart_or_stool(yes),
    pain_in_lower_right_abdominal(yes).
```

Also remove the first clause of `diagnosis(_) :- retractall, fail` or you will be no better off than before.

This is still fairly gross, but it may get you over the hump.

Long term and in general, you probably want the expert system to perform the interview interactively like it does. After all, there is no point to asking someone if they feel heartburn unless they feel flatulence and are eligible for a typhus diagnosis; the symptom of heartburn just isn't relevant to the other two diagnoses (malaria or usus buntu) and figuring out this dependency relation is something only Prolog can do. That doesn't mean that Prolog has to output anything during the diagnosis phase though; you could get the best of both worlds by separating the interview/data collection phase from the result output phase by just collecting all the diagnoses and then outputting them. The result would look like:

```
go :-
    retractall,
    findall(X, diagnosis(X), Diagnoses),
    writeln('diagnoses are: '),
    display_diagnoses(Diagnoses).

display_diagnoses([]).
display_diagnoses([X|Rest]) :-
    write('  '), write(X), nl,
    display_diagnoses(Rest).
```

Running it looks like this:

```
?- go.
fever:yes? : yes.
shivering:yes? : |: yes.
sweating:yes? : |: yes.
headache:yes? : |: yes.
nausea:yes? : |: no.
diagnoses are: 
  malaria
true.

?-
```

This strikes me as a marked improvement without substantial code change. Hope this helps!

Oh, one more thing: replace `retractall :- retract(known(_,_,_))` with `retractall :- retractall(known(_,_,_))`. :)

I would also recommend you format the code more carefully! It is very hard to understand without reformatting it. Code hygiene matters!

Comment: Thank you for your help.